# Laravel checkbox value update

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel and I wanna do a simple checkbox exercise. I wanna input `approved`'s default value as 1. If I click the checkbox, the value is set to 2.

```
<input type="hidden" name="approved" value="1"></input><input type="hidden" name="checkbox" value="2"></input>
```

Here is my script to pass the `approved` value in Ajax to the controller:

```
approved:$('input[name=approved]').val(),
```

Here is my controller:

```
$approved = $request->approved;
```

The result is that no matter whether I click the checkbox, the value is always 1. Can you please help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a few things...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="approved" value="2" {{ old('approved', 1) == 2 ? 'checked' : '' }}>


approved: $('input[name="approved"]:checked').val()

$approved = $request->input('approved', 1);
```